# how to pass multiple arguments into plugin.properties file in eclipse rcp dynamically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i have to give about description in eclipse rcp, so iam using plugin.properties for that.

in properties file version number and build id, i have to pass arguments dynamically.

### this is my plugin.properties file

```
aboutText=My Product is based on Eclipse Platform
Version No: ${versionnumber}
Build id: ${buildid} Welcome to my Product based on Eclipse Product Configuration. A RCP game is encapsulated in it with customized branding elements. This product is developed by Xing Xing Li and Ying Xi Zhao (c) Copyright by authors. All rights reserved
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any support for this.

Since the file is a Java Properties file you could use the Ant `propertyfile` task to modify the file before running your build.